# Loading a ListView from file, only displays every other record

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have created a method to load a ListView from a text file. However, the problem is that my ListView is only displaying every other record. For some reason it only displays even numbered items...2,4,6,etc. I need it to display all the items. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the method...

```
public partial class Admin : Form
{
    const string ITEMSFILE = "items.dat";
    const char DELIM = ',';

    List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();

    public Admin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        load2();

        itemsListView.View = View.Details;

        itemsListView.Columns.Add("ID");
        itemsListView.Columns.Add("Item Name");
        itemsListView.Columns.Add("Cost");
        itemsListView.Columns.Add("Category");

  itemsListView.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
    itemsListView.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
    }

    public void load2()
    {
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(ITEMSFILE, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            string recordIn;
            string[] fields;
            string itemline;
            itemsListView.Items.Clear();
            try
            {
                while ((itemline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {                      
                    recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
                    fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM);
                    itemsListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3] }));            
                }
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                //TODO
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the text files content....

```
1,Bud light,3.50,Drinks
2,Michelob ultra,3.50,Drinks
3,Heineken,4.00,Drinks
4,Miller lite,3.50,Drinks
5,Busch,2.50,Drinks
6,Pabst,2.50,Drinks
```

Example of faulty output...

[image]

UPDATE - REVISED WORKING CODE
Disappointed I was downvoted. Here is my revised working code...

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;

namespace LoadList
{
    public partial class Admin : Form
    {
        const string ITEMSFILE = "items.dat";
        const char DELIM = ',';

        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();

        public Admin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            load2();
        }

        public void load2()
        {
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(ITEMSFILE, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                string recordIn;
                string[] fields;
                string itemline;
                itemsListView.Items.Clear();

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {                      
                    recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
                    fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM);
                    itemsListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3] }));            
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `catch (NullReferenceException)` — WTH is this?

Comment: Try to use a debugger and step through your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading two lines:

```
...
while ((itemline = reader.ReadLine()) != null) <- 1st
{                      
    recordIn = reader.ReadLine(); <- 2nd
    ...
```

Get rid of the 2nd one and use `itemline` instead of `recordIn`

Comment: Ofir, thank you for putting me in the right direction. I changed the condtion on the loop to (!reader.EndOfStream) and it now works great.